# Can we zoom IN zoom OUT chart image using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, mschart, microsoft-chart-controls

In my ASP.NET applicaiton, i have used microsoft chart control and generated Doughnut and Bar charts.

Now, i need to implement ZOOM IN and ZOOM OUT feature.

I could not found any default way in ASP.NET - microsfot chart control to achieve this.

It would be great if any one can suggest through Javascript/JQUERY if achievable.

Below is stuff which able to zoom IN ZOOM OUT but it reduce from actual size and then make it just rest to actual size. I need to increase the size to zoom out.

```
  $('#image').hover(function(){
     $(this).css({width:"100%",height:"100%"});
    },function(){
    $(this).css({width:"50%",height:"50%"});   
  });
```

Thank You
Dhaval Soni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Zoomooz plugin](http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/) may help you.

It easy to implement and it support jquery

You can Zoom the element inside a container

[Jsfiddle to zoom text when click](http://jsfiddle.net/somnath_k/mVf8Z/276/)

```
$("#zoom").click(function () {
    $(this).zoomTo({
        targetsize: 1.0,
        root: $(".container")
    });
});
```

Comment: Its not working. Please suggest any other way in jquery file if we could achieve. Please also see my updated quest.